# Docker services running on some locally and others remotely

Tags: docker, docker-compose

How can I configure docker-compose to use multiple containers where some containers (especially in active development) to be running on your local host computer and other services are containers in remote servers?

In docker-compose.yml

```
rails:
  build: some_path
  volumes: some_volumes

mysql:
  image: xxx
  build: xxxx

nginx:   
  image: xxx
  build: xxxx

other_services:
```

Currently I have all containers running locally and it works fine, but noticed that performance is slow; what if I have, for example, nginx and other_services running remotely - how do I do that? If there is a tutorial link, kindly let me know since didn't find one with google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [docker swarm](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/). You can create a swarm with many nodes (one your local machine one the remote server) and then using docker stack deploy you can deploy your application to those machines.
This is the [tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/swarm-tutorial/).